# I forgot to add butter to my king cake dough

Tags: cake, dough, rising, kneading

I forgot to add butter to my dough when making king cake, I have kneaded it and left it to rise, will it ruin the dough to mix the butter in and then knead and let it rise again?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, if you attempt to combine the butter into the already risen dough, the dough's structure would most likely get ruined.

I wouldn't stress too much over the forgotten butter in the dough though, as the filling will consist of butter as well. Also, you may be able to salvage *some* flakyness by gently folding in thin sheets of butter into the dough.

Answer (score 1):

That’s a shame after you did all that work.  (oops)
I’d make a little melted butter and vanilla and brush the cake w/that  (lightly) before you frost it.